# Creating a sitemap for React Native mobile application and identifying webview screens

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flipper

I'm currently working on a React Native project for a mobile application, targeting both iOS and Android platforms. As part of my development process, I'd like to create a sitemap for the application, which would help me understand the structure of the screens and identify which screens are implemented using webviews and which ones are purely React Native components.

I'm wondering if there are any libraries or tools available that can assist me in generating a sitemap for my React Native project. Specifically, I would like to be able to differentiate between screens that utilize webviews and those that are built purely with React Native components.

I've come across React Native Flipper during my research, but I'm not sure if it provides the specific functionality I'm looking for. If it does, I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to utilize it for this purpose. Alternatively, if there are other recommended libraries or tools that can help me achieve my goal, I would be grateful for any suggestions.

[image]